# Show document withe formation and colors output

Tags: terminal, colors, console, text-formatting

I would like to write a small reminder that will be displayed on my console. I have found this [link](https://misc.flogisoft.com/bash/tip_colors_and_formatting), But I don't know if there is a simpler way to write and display my document with colors.

My idea is to create a document `cmd_info.txt`. then creates a shortcut `cmd_remaind` that launches `printf' %b\n'"$ (cat path_to_cmd_info.txt)"`.

I was looking for a display of this style in the Terminal.
Title in green color, cmd in yellow and info in white.

#### `Title 1`

`cmd1        info
cnd2        info`

#### `Title 2`

`cmd1        info
cnd2        info`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really; such coloring is entirely dependent on the capabilities of your terminal, and `bash`'s only role is to output the correct bytes for the terminal to read.

That said, and *because* coloring is terminal-specific, you can use `tput` to automatically output the correct bytes for your current terminal.

```
green=$(tput setaf 2)
yellow=$(tput setaf 3)
white=$(tput setaf 7)
default=$(tput sgr0)
echo "${green}Title 1$(default)"
echo "${yellow}cmd1${default}        ${yellow}info${default}"
echo "${yellow}cmd2${default}        ${yellow}info${default}"
```

Note that foreground colors 2, 3, and 7 are *abstract*, in that there is no guaranteed that they are *actually* green, yellow, and white, respectively. Those are the conventional colors, but a terminal emulator can be configured to use different colors for each abstract slot.